# How can I see the list of locations embedded in an application that is searched when resolving @rpath references to libraries?

Tags: macos

`otool -L someApp` Shows a bunch of frameworks referenced as

```
@rpath/../Frameworks/Blah.framework/...
```

My understanding is that the loader/dynamic linker uses a list of locations which are embedded in `someApp` to generate possible paths to the frameworks by substituting them in place of the the `@rpath` directives. But I don't know how to see that list of locations.

So how do I see that list?

Answer (score 1):

The paths that the app contributes to the rpath are part of its load commands. You can show the load commands using `otool -lV <path>`. To load commands adding paths to the rpath have the command `LC_RPATH`. So, to see all of those, you can use:

```
otool -lV <path> | grep -B 1 -A 2 LC_RPATH
```

All of that said, the rpath is dynamic. When a process loads a library, that library can add things to the rpath, at least for the things it depends on.